# Simplest way to confirm payment via PayPal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

what's the best way to simply get feedback from PayPal to confirm that your customer paid? It looks as if the answer is IPN - if so, my followup question is, can I enable IPN for only specific buttons? I don't want PayPal pinging my IPN listener for purchases that don't require any kind of IPN integration.

I'm all about Agile and YAGNI, and therefore I don't want to do anything that is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the [IPN Documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro) that have provided by PayPal. To use IPN, the simple way is to have `invoice` id for a transaction that you want to track. In the IPN listener page, you will get `ipn_data` and one of the field is the `invoice`. Using this id, you should get the data from your own transaction database, then change the status to reflect the payment status in PayPal.

In my code, usually I set status to `unpaid`, direct the user to paypal to do payment, and in IPN listener I will set the status to `paid`.

PayPal provide [sample code](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code) so you can start right away. You can also see other PayPal documentation in [this page](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_documentation).

Comment: Is it your app's job to create the invoice id, or does Paypal create it? Is it possible to create your own ID and make paypal notify you with that specific ID?

Comment: Your app should create it and pass it to Paypal. Also, make sure that it's unique, because paypal will check if that particular invoice id of your app have been paid or not.

Comment: Thanks for the info, is there constraints on that ID, as in length, characters.. etc? I was wondering if I could pass a HMAC hash there so that way I don't need to store these temporary IDs.

Comment: invoice Pass-through variable you can use to identify your Invoice Number for this purchase. If omitted, no variable is passed back.
Length: 127 characters (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) You better manage this, so you could display purchase history to your website users.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily include which IPN listener to use for in a button's parameters.

If you don't have a default location set on PayPal's website, then your IPN listener will only get pinged for those buttons that do have one set.

The PayPal form variable in question is "notify_url".

Here's an example subscription button, same variable for anything else though.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/x-click-butcc-subscribe.gif"
            border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online."
            onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Click', 'PayPalMonthSub', 'SubscribePage']);" />
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1"
            height="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@yourdomain.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value=" Monthly Subscription" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF" />
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="4.99" />
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M" />
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://yourdomain.com/subscribe/thanks.aspx" />
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://yourdomain.com/subscribe" />
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="/http://yourdomain.com/IPN.aspx" />
</form>
```

If you need the default notification url set on your account then you will only be able to stop your handler being pinged by including a different handler in buttons that don't need it. If PayPal doesn't get an HTTP200 from a handler though it will keep trying it so I wouldn't advise setting anything to a non existent URI.